# Should I create one NSOperationQueue per UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, afnetworking-2

In almost every `UIViewController` I have a bunch of `AFHTTPRequestOperation`s and I have to properly handle any kind of cancel (pressing cancel button, going back in `UINavigationController`'s stack, etc.). I was wondering if creating one `NSOperationQueue` per each `UIViewController` and adding to it all operations called within controller would be a proper way to go? I was aiming for cancelling all operations `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] cancelAllOperations]` but this will kill all operations already started, especially those called from previous `UIViewController`. Or should I create property for each operation, call it in `viewWillDissappear:(BOOL)animated` and set if statement for cancel state in success block?

Comment: If you use AFHTTPClient and inherited that, then it has NSOperationQueue and you could use any of the method that starts with enqueue* to add it to the list AFHTTPClient has. Usually I will have a separate NSOperationQueue per controller if that controller needs to download images or large amount of data so it would be easier for me to cancel/pause the operation. If one of the controller only need to download a 3 MB file or something then I would probably have a separate NSOperation property just pointing to that operation and start/cancel it manually when the user enters/leaves.

Comment: Your private queues will *definitely* not be `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` instances are cheap to create and each has its own operation queue, so it is easy to cancel all of a given `UIViewController`'s operations:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self.requestOperationManager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
}
```

This will cancel any request created through `self.requestOperationManager`. You can create the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` in your `UIViewController`'s init method.

I recommend cancelling operations in your view controller's dealloc method, as you know it will no longer be needed.

Comment: I'd be careful about using `viewWillDisappear:`, as it's called in many instances (e.g. presenting modal view controllers), and possibly not the one the user wants. I'd recommend calling it in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: Good point, I was lead by the question. I've updated the answer!

Comment: @GuyKogus: even using something like this: `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController && self.isBeingDismissed) {
        DDLogDebug(@"back or dismissed!");
        [self.operation cancel];
    }
}` ?

Comment: What about when a navigation controller pushes another view controller on top? Maybe that's caught by your tests, but you never know when, where why or how that method will be called. Your best bet is to call it on `dealloc`. If you want you can `suspend` and `resume` the operation queue on `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: tried `dealloc`, tried `viewWillDisappear` - nothing worked. I call on manager `POST:path parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)` and in both cases I call `[self.requestOperationManager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations]` but still nothing...

Comment: finally got it :) `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated { [super viewWillDisappear:animated]; if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController || self.isBeingDismissed) { DDLogDebug(@"back or dismissed!"); [self.manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations]; } }` problem was I used `&&` not `||`. Dealloc isn't even called, but thanks for reply!

Comment: thanks for help, though exact solution that worked for me is in my answer, if anyone needed

Answer (score 0):

Tried David Caunt answer, but didn't work for me. `dealloc` wasn't called when I pushed back button, so I guess the best way to cancel operations is to call it in `viewWillDisappear:` (my bad was to use `&&` not `||` - silly mistake, but easiest things are often hardest to find)

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated]; 
if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController && self.isBeingDismissed){
    DDLogDebug(@"back or dismissed!"); 
    [self.manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations]; } 
}
```